# pip install {package} очень долго работает

Tags: python, pip

Пытаюсь установить пакеты, а по итогу pip install просто зависает и ничего не делает (даже через 5 минут).

```
pip 21.3.1 from /home/shandori/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

От пакета это не зависит. Что делать и куда копать? Команда ниже тоже просто зависает.

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Сам сайт pypi.org работает судя по проверке.

```
# curl -I https://pypi.org
HTTP/2 200
```

P.S. До этого все работало.

P.S.S. Оказывает проблема в том, что нужно ждать 5+ минут, почему так и что делать?

Comment: есть идеи,почему pip uninstall не работает? Будто выполняется, но время идёт, а ничего не происходит. Работаю в Jupiter notebook

Answer (score 0):

У меня похожая ситуация, разбираюсь, дополню как окончательно пойму, но судя по всему дело в провайдере, то есть проблема на стороне телекома. К примеру когда я конекчу инет с телефона, на 3g LTE pip начинает работать как должен, то есть скачивает все за пару секунд. Тоже самое с телеграм ботами, отказываются быстро работать с домашнего сервера через МГТС инет иногда вообще просто не работают, но как только подключаю 3g-LTE, или на vps сразу начинает летать. Временное решение конкретно Вашего вопроса - раздать интернет  с телефона.